# How to remove newlines from csv files?

Tags: python

How can I remove the newlines from my csv file?  This is what my current output looks like: 
`{'\n': ('', ''), '0-586-08997-7\n': ('Kurt Vonnegut', 'Breakfast of Champions'), '978-0-14-302089-9\n': ('Lloyd Jones', 'Mister Pip'), '1-877270-02-4\n': ('Joe Bennett', 'So Help me Dog'), '0-812-55075-7': ('Orson Scott Card', 'Speaker for the Dead')}`

and this is what the output is *suppose* to look like:

`{'0-586-08997-7': ('Kurt Vonnegut', 'Breakfast of Champions'),
'978-0-14-302089-9': ('Lloyd Jones', 'Mister Pip'),
'1-877270-02-4': ('Joe Bennett', 'So Help me Dog'),
'0-812-55075-7': ('Orson Scott Card', 'Speaker for the Dead')}`

I don't want to use any of the in built csv tools or whatever because we haven't done those in class so I doubt we'd need to use them in these questions.

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):
    """docstring"""
    file = open(filename, "r")
    library = {}


    for line in file:
        line = line.split(",")
        tup = (line[0], line[1])

        library[line[2]] = tup
    return library


print(isbn_dictionary("books.csv"))
```

Comment: Is `line.replace("\n", "")`an option?

Comment: if I do that I get this stuff at the start `'': ('', '')` but the rest of the \n's in the dictionary go away.

Comment: We were given a csv file to turn into a dictionary with the first value of each line to be the key then the remaining to be the values of those keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal modifications of your code:

```
def isbn_dictionary(filename):
    """docstring"""
    file = open(filename, "r")
    library = {}


    for line in file:
        line = line.split(",")
        if line[0]: # Only append if there is a value in the first column
            tup = (line[0], line[1])

            library[line[2].strip()] = tup # get rid of newlines in the key
    file.close() # It's good practice to always close the file when done. Normally you'd use "with" for handling files.
    return library


print(isbn_dictionary("books.csv"))
```

Empty strings are *falsey*, so this will not add to your `library` dict if the first entry of a row is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the first line by adding `next(file)` before your for loop, and call `.strip()` on the ISBN.

Comment: how would I ignore the first line?